# Monogdb $expr with multiple level of nesting

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I don't know whether this is possible or not and the doc for [$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) doesn't seem to mention it as well, but I'm trying to compare two fields where one is a hash type and the other is an array of hashes. I'm trying to query for records where the hash field is equal to the first hash element in the array of hashes. Here is my collection layout:

```
{
  _id: "Some ID",
  answers: [ { staff_id: 1, answer: { dob: true, type: true } } ,
  qa_answer: { dob: true, type: true }
}
```

The query expression I've tried is:

```
collection.find({ '$expr': { '$eq': ['$answers.0.answer', '$qa_answer'] } })
```

But this doesn't seem to work. I thought it was the nested dot notation that was the problem but I've tried the following and it worked:

```
collection.find({ 'answers.0.answer': { "dob": true, "type": true } })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay I finally got it to work, it turns out the dot notation was the issue. Here's the query I ended up with:

```
collection.find({ 
  '$expr': { 
    '$eq': [ 
      { '$arrayElemAt': [ '$answers.answer', 0 ] }, 
      '$qa_answer'
    ] 
  } 
})
```